# uniform continuity only using theorems

Tags: uniform-continuity

$f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$. Prove that f is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$ . Can this be proved by using the theorems only, not using the definition directly?

I approach to the answer like this :
since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$ holds, so $f(x)$ is bounded everywhere in $[0,\infty)$. Now $[0,1],[1,2],[2,3].....$ are closed and bounded, so $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on each of $[0,1],[1,2],[2,3].....$ now $[0,\infty)=[0,1]\cup[1,2]\cup[2,3].....$ so $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$ . I approach this way only because $f(x)$ is bounded. the But I don't understand if I am right or not. Is this approach correct ?

Comment: " Can this be proved by using the theorems only?" Perhaps you could use the following **Theorem:** *Let $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous.*
What I want to mean with this comment, is that you should tell us what Theorems you can use in order to prove the claim using them

Comment: sorry... my text book has this theorem in special examples. I could not understand that it is theorem itself..

Comment: What is a *Theorem*? For a given result, some textbooks will call it a theorem, other will call it a proposition or a lemma and some other an exercise or a remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want to make use of the theorem that each continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous. Then choose $n>0$ so big that for $x>n$ we have $|f(x)|<\varepsilon/2$. For $[0,n+1]$ use the theorem. QED.

Answer (score 1):

Say a function $g$ has compact support if there exists $A$ so that $g(x)=0$ for all $x$ with $|x|>A$.

Theorem: A continuous function with compact support is uniformly continuous.

Theorem: If $f_n$ is uniformly continuous and $f_n\to f$ uniformly then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Theorem: If $f$ satisfies the conditions you give then there exist continuous functions $f_n$ with compact support such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

Comment: Why not simply taking only one theorem namely: Let $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous.